# Brasero not appearing in the software store

Tags: gnome, 16.04, software-sources

using this for the first time and trying to burn an .iso onto a DVD, but Ubuntu doesn't give me the option to write to disk, and when i search for Brasero it doesn't appear. I've tried using the command prompt too and that hasn't worked either, does anyone know what the issue is and how it could be resolved ?

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion, try `k3b`.

Comment: You can still install it via command line:  `sudo apt install brasero`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Software Updater, click on Settings and check the boxes for "Canonical Parteners" under "Other Software" in the software updater settings.

Also, Choose "Main Server" for Ubuntu server under "Ubuntu Software".

This should solve the issue.